# C# HTTP Request does not work as intended as the site is still performing the search

Tags: c#, http, get, request, response

I'm trying to read content of a website. (lolnexus.com)
Therefore I use:

```
        HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

        Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
        Console.WriteLine(_Answer.ReadToEnd());
```

This works, but not for my scenario.
The problem I cant seem to solve is that this is a search.. for example: www.lolnexus.com/EUW/search?name=NAMEHERE&region=EUW

Reading the response returns the "loading/searching" website, because the site needs like 4 seconds to come up with the results. I obviously want to read the result of the search and not the the "search in progress" website.

Comment: Given it requires time, have you considered making your code wait? or keep trying and checking if it has a real answer or not?

Comment: I have tryed to put a Sleep after/before the  
HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
just as Slashy also suggested. But it still did return the seraching site..

Comment: Fire up Fiddler or your browsers Network inspector to see what that URL actually does; It triggers a GET to `http://www.lolnexus.com/ajax/get-game-info/EUW.json?name=NAMEHERE` which would contain the final response and so is what you need to access.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex, you solved my problem. Thank you a lot! Sadly I can't mark this comment as answer..

Answer (score 0):

Make a http request

```
  HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
```

and then use a `Thread.Sleep(3000)`//time you think the website will load.
Only then,read the result! and if its still loading you can make a request again and wait a little longer.
I know it's not the best solution,but i cant think about other idea except checking the result and looping for request...

Comment: That was my first attempt, too. But it doenst work :/